# How we can update our website created in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I know first we want to modify and reupload our site. Can we create any software for updating databases instead of direct modification of the database?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a tool that will apply changes from one environment to another? In which case look into [Redgate's SQL tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just released a framework can help you to update your project. It's the first release of my project. You can find it in the following url.

http://mep.codeplex.com